# Group structure on arbitrary topological spaces

Tags: reference-request, topological-groups, big-list

> **Definition.** Let $(G,\ast)$ be any group. Then $G$ will be said to be a topological group if there exists a topology on $G$ such that the map $f:G\times G\to G$ defined by $f(x,y)=xy^{-1}$ for all $(x,y)\in G\times G$ is continuous.

Now observe that in this definition it is important to note that we *first* have a group and then the topology which makes $f$ cotinuous. In other words, **we impose topological stricture on a group**.

**My question**

1. Is it possible to **impose group structure on a topological space**? I don't think that it is possible always. So my question is, if $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space then under which condition(s) does there exists a binary operation $\ast:X\times X\to X$ such that $(X,\ast)$ is a group?
2. If there is any related research in mathematics literature then can you please let me know about some of those?

---

It has been pointed out (see below) that this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707066/on-which-topological-spaces-can-we-give-a-group-structure-to-make-it-a-topologi?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, I don't think that they are for the reason as explained in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869221/group-structure-on-arbitrary-topological-spaces#comment5921378_2869221). *It is also not clear to me that imposing a group structure on a topological space (if it's possible of course) is expected to result in a topological group.*

Comment: @LeeMosher: Not sure that this question is an *exact* duplicate of the linked question. In the question it is explicitly asked that "can we give a group structure on $X$ so that it becomes a topological group", whereas my question simply is "can we give a group structure on $X$". Can you explain to me how they are duplicate?

Comment: Are you sure you really mean that you want to completely ignore the given topological structure on the set $X$? Because [every nonempty set has a group structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105433/does-every-set-have-a-group-structure) (assuming the axiom of choice), which totally alters the perception of what your question is about...

Comment: @LeeMosher: I think I have been a bit imprecise. Suppose that $(X,\text{Cl})$ be a closure space and consider the topology induced from it. What I would like to see is a group structure on $X$ using this $\text{Cl}$ operator, for example?

Comment: For example in case of topological group we have a group $G$, then the method of imposing a topological structure on $G$ is to bring into picture the continuity of $f$ as mentioned above. For it we only used the binary operation on $G$. I was expecting something similar to that. Some function from $X\times X$ using only $\text{Cl}$ for example @LeeMosher.

Comment: Can anyone please explain why in spite of my pointing out the the linked question is not a duplicate of the current question, it has been closed as a duplicate of *that* question?

Comment: @JohnMa: Would you mind to explain? Not necessarily here but [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72901/general-chat-with-user-170039) will also be fine.

Comment: To be clear, your question *as it is written* it is a duplicate. In your comment you attempted to reformulate what you were asking in the language of closure operators, but if you want to do that then it is best to do it in a new question. If you want to try to write a new question along those lines, please feel free to do so.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Strangely enough, in my addition to the question, I explained why precisely the question as it is written is not a duplicate (at least not of the linked question). Could you address why that explanation is faulty? (It must be, because otherwise, I see very little point in stating that the question is a duplicate of the linked one.)

Comment: I shall give it a try, but I think this will be my last word in this thread. In mathematics, given two categories (in this case, the topological category and the group category) there is a natural problem which arises, namely to form a kind of mix of the two categories. This is what your words mean *mathematically*, when you write **impose topological structure on a group** and when you write **impose group structure on a topological space**.

Comment: Although there is no completely natural way to solve this problem when given an arbitrary pair of categories to merge, nonetheless there is an important constraint on the solution: the structures imposed by the two categories should be compatible with each other. For merging the "topological" category and the "group" category into the "topological group" category, the solution which satisfies this constraint turns out to be very natural, namely: the group operation $G \times G \to G$ and the inversion operation $G \mapsto G$ should be continuous.

Comment: So, your question is the same as the duplicate question, both of which ask how to merge the topology category and the group category, and it has the same answer, which is the category of topological groups. As I said, if you wish to ask a different question about closure operators rather than topologies, please feel free to do so.

Comment: Very interesting comments. Thanks @LeeMosher.

Answer (score 2):

There is a gigantic literature on topological groups, with specialized literature on many special kinds of topological groups. You might start with Lie groups (topological groups which are manifolds). If you like number theory, you will discover that the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb Q_p$ are a topological group which is locally homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

No, it is not always possible to impose a group structure on a topological space.

For example, a topological group $G$ must be *homogeneous* which means that for any two points $x,y \in G$ there exists a homeomorphism $L : G \to G$ such that $L(x)=y$: simply use the map $L(g)=f(g,y^{-1}x)$. But there are many nonhomogeneous topological spaces. The first one that comes to mind is $[0,1]$, which has no homeomorphism taking $0$ to $1/2$.

There are even homogeneous topological spaces on which one cannot impose a group structure, in particular many manifolds. You learn in the theory of Lie groups that if a topological group $G$ is a compact manifold then the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) of $G$ equals zero. However, there are plenty of compact manifolds with nonzero Euler characterestic, starting with the 2-sphere $S^2$ which has Euler characteristic equal to $2$.

Comment: Hmmm... now I see that this question is a duplicate.