# Is there a topological group structure on the Baire Space?

Tags: topological-groups, the-baire-space, polish-groups

The sum of two irrationals might not be irrational so we can't use that; Also $\mathbb N$ is not a group so there's no obvious way to define a group structure in it seen as $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ either.  [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2707155/957774) gives some necessary conditions for a topological space to be possible to turn into a topological group. The Baire space clearly satisfies 1,4 and 5; intuitively i think it also satisfies 2 but i'm not sure how to prove it, and i have no idea for 3.

Is there a topological group structure on the Baire Space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Baire space is $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the product topology so it has an abelian topological group structure given by pointwise addition. $\mathbb{Z}$ can be replaced with any countable discrete group.

Comment: That was embarassing haha

Comment: Since this question was trivial, is it okay if i edit it as i thought of a follow up question?

Comment: That's usually frowned upon but if it's not too different from the original question I guess that's fine.