# Is there an indecomposable topological group structure on the Baire Space?

Tags: topological-groups, the-baire-space

Follow up to [this follow up question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4506702/957774) Is there an indecomposable group $G$ ie, a group that can't be written in the form $A\times B$ where both $A$ and $B$ are nontrivial groups along with a topology on it that makes it homeomorphic to the Baire space $\mathbb N ^{\mathbb N}$ and makes it into a topological group?

Comment: Why Close vote to this question? If anything, i think my previous questions of which this is a follow up would be the ones that could be closed as they turned out to be trivial. Hopefully this one is interesting unlike those..

Comment: Look, there's really just a lot of ways to modify the construction such that the result we get is still homeomorphic to the Baire space. We haven't used semidirect products yet!

Comment: That answers my question. Should i delete it?

Comment: Well, again, there's still work to do to prove that such a thing is actually indecomposable. I haven't thought through any specific example in detail.

Comment: Isn't $S_\infty$ with its usual topology (pointwise convergence) homeomorphic to the Baire space?